# How to prevent memory optimized tables from blowing out OPT_MEMORY_OPTIMIZED\$HKv2

Tags: sql-server

I use a Microsoft SQL Server 2017 database, Developer edition. Just updated to latest version (RTM-CU17) (KB4515579) - 14.0.3238.1 (X64).

It uses memory optimized tables. When I run a very large stored procedure which deletes many records in many tables, I find that the database creates more and more big files in the directory
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\OPT_MEMORY_OPTIMIZED\$HKv2

This until the disk is full.

I use CHECKPOINT in strategic places in the stored procedure. But this doesn't stop the growth of that directory.

How can I stop the growth of the OPT_MEMORY_OPTIMIZED\$HKv2 directory?

Comment: This seems, to me, like it would be better asked on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), rather than SO, due to the fact it's more to do with Query Performance (and avoiding over utilisation of memory).

Comment: @Larnu Thanks, I've done that now.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem was that:
1) my database was in Full recovery mode; and
2) I wasn't doing backups of my logs.

Once I set my database to Simple recovery mode (database Properties | Options), the problem went away.